# Issue getting mouse coordinate

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I use below code to capture mouse coordinate, and bind it to a `div(container).` and there's one more div called `subDiv` inside `container`. I found that no matter where I move inside `subDiv`, the coordinate is always the one I just entered `subDiv` (e.g. I enter `subDiv` at (10,10), no mater where I move in `subDiv`, the coordinate is always (10,10)).
Anybody know why?

```
var x,y;
var e = e||window.event;
return {
  x:e.clientX+document.body.scrollLeft+document.documentElement.scrollLeft,     
  y:e.clientY+document.body.scrollTop+document.documentElement.scrollTop 
    
    };
```

Comment: There's nowhere near enough code to understand what's happening in your system. What event are you binding to? `mouseenter` or `mousemove`? What elements are you binding the event to?

Comment: @lan,thx for ur reply,I used mouseover and and got the issue i mentioned above.Issue solved after I changed it to mousemove:)

Answer (score 1):

What you pasted works as following demos. Check other code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function test(e){
                var x,y;
                var e = e||window.event;
                return {
                    x:e.clientX+document.body.scrollLeft+document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
                    y:e.clientY+document.body.scrollTop+document.documentElement.scrollTop
                }; 
            }
            function myFunction(event){
                var x = test(event);
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x.x + '.' + x.y;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="subDiv" style="width:199px;height:99px;border:1px solid"  onmousemove="myFunction(event)"></div>
        </div>
        <p id="demo"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```